# Why I'm getting this error "You're not in the targeted group for this item" when trying to download my app on Android Market

Tags: android, google-play

After publishing the app to the Android Market, I'm getting "You're not in the targeted group for this item" error when I'm viewing the app in Android Market. And when I'm viewing it with browser it says that "This app is incompatbile with your ..." The weird thing is that I can see on the developer console that the application is available for the phones I've tried to look and install the app. Also I can't find the application with the search, no matter how or on which device I'm trying to search it. I've tried with 3 different phones (HTC Desire, ZTE Blade and Samsung 5460, and also with 2 different Google-accounts and without logging in to google.

Here is the AndroidManifest.xml for the app.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.my.package"
    android:versionCode="5"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="8" />

    <permission android:name="com.my.package.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.my.package.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>



    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="false">

        <receiver android:name="com.my.package.CloudReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="com.my.package.beta" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="com.my.package.beta" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>


        <activity            
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".NameInputActivity"
            android:theme="@style/background_style">
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/background_style" >

            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:scheme="http" android:host="host.com" android:pathPattern="/v/.*" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity 
            android:name=".NewConversationActivity"
            android:theme="@style/background_style"></activity>
        <activity 
            android:name="com.my.package.MultipleContactsActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I have declared my own permission because I'm using C2DM. Could that be a problem that Android Market is filtering my application.

What could be reason that I'm getting those errors and any ideas how to get rid of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem fixed itself. I don't really still doesn't know what was the solution, but after sleeping over night and trying again at the morning I was able to download application and also find it with the search.

My best guess would be that there is just some latency in the Android Market.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will necessarily fix it, but there is a a typo here (dot-dot) after `package`

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.my.package..permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

**Edit:** Thought that might have been a typo when opening question...Might want to tighten up these two [uses-permissions](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-element.html) to match the spec

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>
```

to

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Again, not sure if it will fix the larger issue, but might as well rule it out while cleaning up manifest

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it was just a typo I made when creating this question. In the real AndroidManifest.xml that line is correct. But thanks anyway!

Comment: I also cleaned the manifest with your corrections, but that didn't work either. It just "started to work" after sleeping over night. But thanks for your reply!